# Iterate over elements where not all the elements should have a value

Tags: c++

I'm not sure how to describe this. I have to iterate through objects which are connected by pointers with each other, However the first element shouldn't have values stored in its class just the pointer to the next element.

I came up with a small class hierarchy. If I use it like that I have to cast the base class to the derived element. It only seems to work with a dirty cast.

Is there a better solution?

Here the example code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Basenode {
    Basenode* next;
};

struct Skipnode : Basenode {
    Skipnode(int in_key, int in_value);

    int key;
    int value;
};

Skipnode::Skipnode(int in_key, int in_value)
    : key{ in_key }, value{ in_value }
{
}

int main()
try {
    Basenode head;              // no key and value
    Skipnode first(4, 2);       // key and value
    Skipnode second(8, 2);

    Basenode* p = &head;

    head.next = &first;         // fine
    first.next = &second;       // fine

//  p = p->next->key;           // not accesible because is Basenode not derrived Skipnode

    std::cout << static_cast<Skipnode*>(p->next)->key;  // fine but diryt cast  slicing ?

    std::cin.get();
}
catch (std::runtime_error& e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << "\n";
    std::cin.get();
}
catch (...) {
    std::cerr << "unknown error " << "\n";
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Edit:  it was asked int the comments why i need this anyway. I think i gave a to limited example.

I need it to implement a skiplist. Many algorithms of it require to start on a element before the first element. The head element. I could make it a normal node and put in dummy values for the values but it didnt seem right. So now i came up with this ugly solution from youre suggestions to start on the head elements.

Heres a snippet with the copy constructor as example.

```
class Skiplist {
public:
    //...
    Skiplist(const Skiplist& other);                // copy constructor
    //...
private:
    struct Skipnode;                // forward declaration so Basenode can have Skiplist*

    struct Basenode {                                       // Empty node, mainly created to represent head element. 
                                                            // Is there a way to get a empty head with no key / values without using this ?
        Basenode(int in_level);
        Basenode(const std::vector<Skipnode*>& in_next);

        std::vector <Skipnode*> next;
    };

    struct Skipnode : Basenode {                                    // derived so with Basenode* we can start the iteration of the node on head
        Skipnode(value_type val, int in_level);
        Skipnode(value_type val, const std::vector<Skipnode*>& in_next);

        value_type value;       // first key / second mapped type = value

                                //key_type key;
                                //mapped_type value;
    };

    Basenode head{ 0 };                 // element before first element containg pointers to all the first elements of each level

    //...
};


Skiplist::Skiplist(const Skiplist& other)       // copy constructor
    :head{ other.head }, top_level{ other.top_level }, random_engine{ other.random_engine }
    // on the first level let the other Skiplist present its elements and make a deep copy of them
    // now still the higher levels point to the other node so this is fixed in the second part
    // then the next level pointers are installed linked to the elements of the new node
{
    if (top_level == 0) return;     // no elements are present so dont bother to allocate nodes

    {
        // installment of lowest level, each element is located here
        Skipnode* other_node = other.head.next[0];
        Basenode* current_position = &head;

        while (other_node != nullptr) {
            Skipnode* new_node = new Skipnode{ other_node->value,other_node->next };

            current_position->next[0] = new_node;
            current_position = current_position->next[0];
            other_node = other_node->next[0];
        }
        current_position->next[0] = nullptr;
    }

    // installment of the other levels
    for (size_type curr = 1; curr < top_level; ++curr) {

        Basenode* current_position = &head;                         // the current position of the level[curr]
        Skipnode* next_position = current_position->next[curr];     // next position after curr containing still pointers to the other skiplist
        Basenode* lowest_position = &head;                          // lowest level position used to find the new pointers and attach them "behind" current

        while (lowest_position != nullptr && next_position != nullptr) {

            if (lowest_position->next[0]->value.first == next_position->value.first) {      // check by unique key, address of next pos is still of the other skiplist

                current_position->next[curr] = lowest_position->next[0];        // lowest is the valid address of new node
                current_position = current_position->next[curr];
                next_position = next_position->next[curr];                      // go to next element of other node

                if (next_position == nullptr) {                     // case end is reached
                    current_position->next[curr] = nullptr;
                    current_position = current_position->next[curr];
                }
            }
            else {      // forward position of lowest level until other key == next position key
                lowest_position = lowest_position->next[0];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See here for a basic explanation how a skiplist is organized:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list

The whole code is on codereview:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/197752/non-generic-skip-list-implementation-in-c-version-2

Comment: Why does class `BaseNode` exist at all, just for the sake of saving two `int`s?  Or is your real use-case more complex than this?

Comment: Casting pointers to the correct type is not considered "dirty" and, as long as it's the correct type, then it's not slicing either. That's really how *upcasting* is designed to work.

Comment: Also note that `p = p->next[0]->key` is invalid because another reason: `p->next` is not an "array" of pointers.

Comment: Oh don't forget to terminate the list, by setting the last pointer to null.

Comment: yes is just simplified the real use case. i fixed the vector issue to a single pointer

Comment: Lastly, you don't really need to use your own home-made list, unless it's for a school exercise or something similar. Just use a `std::vector<Basenode*>`, where `Basenode` is modified to keep all common data but *no* "next" link.

Comment: Please clarify whether your question is about iterating or downcasting.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude s/upcasting/downcasting. Anyway, downcasting *should* be avoided. There are patterns to work around it.

Comment: If the code you have is working, then perhaps what you need is a [*code review*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour)?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yeah I saw it a little to late to edit it.

Comment: *Is there a better solution?* It depends on what your ultimate goals are. Do you expect to see more types derived from `Basenode`? Do you expect to see a `List` class that would provide higher level, list manipulation functions?

Comment: i updated with a snipped. I also have a code review going on for the implementation of the list. since i have more design concerns : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/197752/non-generic-skip-list-implementation-in-c-version-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way:

Forward-declare `Skipnode`, and in `BaseNode`, use a pointer to `SkipNode`, this way you don't have to cast:

```
struct Skipnode;
struct Basenode {
    Skipnode* next;
};
```

Also, to illustrate how this design where `Skipnode` inherits from `Basenode` could make sense (related to the discussion in the comments), we can imagine having a member in `Basenode` counting how many elements are next (counting the one in the `next` member and its successors)

Comment: Yep, that's not bad. But _what's the point of class BaseNode_?  Do we _need_ an entire class just to hold a single pointer?  Or is the real-life situation more complex than that?  (And, if so, why?)

Comment: @PaulSanders This class could contain a mutex to protect the datastructure in a concurrent context, or it could contain a counter to keep track of the number of elements, etc...

Comment: Then it's a class for iterating through or generally looking after a list of `SkipNode`s.  That's its job and nothing more.  What it most definitely is **not** is something that `SkipNode` needs to (or should) derive from.  That's what's wrong here - the OP's class hierarchy, and that's the point I've been trying to make all along.

Comment: @PaulSanders You're right, but in that case, I'll argue that if we want to know how many successors every element has, we can put that counter here (if it's a chained list for example).

Comment: Yes, a class to manage the list has value, updated my answer.

Comment: You didn't understand me, I was saying you're right because we can't have a std::mutex here because there would be one for every value. But this design makes sense to have a counter counting the next elements. Sorry if I wasn't being clear enough in my choice of words.

Comment: Did you read my updated answer?  Such a mutex would go in my proposed `SkipNodeList` class - because that's where it belongs - and this class manages, um, a list of `SkipNode`s, and is _not_ the parent class of `SkipNode`.  This is pretty basic stuff, really.

Comment: I'm basing my answer on what the actual question was. But your design is fine, too, it just doesn't exactly answer the question asked.

Comment: That was intentional :)

Comment: the reason i need is i implement a skiplist. the element before the first element in each level is called head. this element has just pointers to the first element. it shouldnt contain values. i will explain more in detail tonight when i have computer access.

Comment: @Sandro OK, yes, please do that.

Answer (score 2):

All the things @SomeProgrammerDude is saying, or:

I don't see a need for class `BaseNode` at all.  Why can't we just have (all other things being equal):

```
SkipNode *head = &first;
...
```

Or better yet a class called (for example) `SkipNodeList` that handles all aspects of managing and iterating through a list of `SkipNode`s.

Of course, this is all a bit silly anyway, just use `std::list` (or `std::forward_list`) for this and benefit from all that STL goodness.

Or you can derive from one of these to add your own functionality (such as a mutex to make the list threadsafe or keeping track of the number of elements currently in the list, as suggested by @iMajuscule).